# How to read different entries from database for multilanguage site with Codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, multilingual

I couldn't find answer for this question... I'm making a multilanguage web site based on Codeigniter and MySQL database. For the static language texts I'm using the built in lang function and according the first segment of the URL /en/ /fr/... I'm loading the appropriate language file, but how do I load and display the corresponding data from the database? How do I even keep the data in the database? I have products table and half of the entries are numerical values, but the other half are texts that should be kept in 2 or 3 languages.

I have my logic to keep name_en and name_fr, description_en and description_fr... all of these in the same table, so I will double those rows as I add new language.
When I will be making a Select query, I will be passing the segment "en" to the query and concanate at the end of name_ or description_ so it would become name_en or description_fr or category_es.

I hope that there is much better way, and some of you who have already worked with this will help me through.

Answer (score 0):

I am usign two table for multilangage support. First table include item fields. For example date, vote and etc. Second table for languages fields.

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nested_category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_file` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(0) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `item_lang` (
  `item_lang_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lang_id` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `url_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `meta_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `meta_description` text,
  `meta_keywords` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_lang_id`)
);
```

If you need a row try like this.

```
function get_row( $id, $lg='tr'){

        $arr = array($id, $lg);

        $sql    = " SELECT ".$this->_table.".*, ".$this->_table_lang.".*
                     FROM ".$this->_table." 
                LEFT JOIN ".$this->_table_lang." 
                       ON ".$this->_table.".".$this->_table."_id = ".$this->_table_lang.".".$this->_table."_id 
                    WHERE ".$this->_table.".".$this->_table."_id = ? 
                      AND ".$this->_table_lang.".lang_id=?";

        $data   = $this->db->query($sql, $arr); 

        return ($data->row());
    }
```

Comment: This is more optimized solution that the one I pointed? Actually I keep as much rows in the second table as I have languages on the web site?

Comment: I think you have to use variable values in the table columns. not in table names. its not a good strategy for future.